# Google map with decimal degree or DD location on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I dont know if google has a function like this or not.
What i have in my db is DD (decimal degrees). it is stored in the db like this 36.308428 -95.316914

What i would like to do is pull this info from the db and make a link with the DD in the link and open it up in a pop up window of some kind and display a map with a marker on it corresponding to DD.

Is this possible?

I found this but what i dont like about it is that it is embedded in another persons website. I would rather just have the map and nothing else on the page.

http://www.gps-coordinates.net/latitude-longitude/36.308428/-95.316914/10/roadmap

Answer (score 1):

Try this php code.

```
/* code to select the coordinates from your databases here*/
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$DD = $row['lat'].','.$row['long'];
echo '<script>window.location = "https://www.google.gr/maps/place/'.$DD.'"</script>';
```

Comment: Thank you for that info that info. I found something a little different that was more like i was wanting. But yours got me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Here is more what i was looking for.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo '<a href="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=';
  echo $row['latitude'] . " ," . $row['longitude'];
  echo '&zoom=18&size=1000x500&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C';
  echo $row['latitude'] . " ," . $row['longitude'];
  echo '"> map </a> <br><br>';

}
```